# Rest Api query on Survey list is not working in sharepoint2016

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am **facing issue with Author field**. Below query is working on normal list. But it's **not working on Survey list**. Help me on this issue
It is showing error message like
"The field 'Author' of type 'User' cannot be used in the query filter expression."

Query is: /_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('List Title')/items?$select=Id,AuthorId&$filter=(AuthorId eq UserID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Survey list is the special type of list, whose Author field is not the same as in other lists. I got the Author field definition through CSOM, and there are two different attributes in it:

- Sortable="FALSE"
- Filterable="FALSE"

The field definition is as follows:

```
    <Field ID="{1df5e554-ec7e-46a6-901d-d85a3881cb18}" ColName="tp_Author" RowOrdinal="0" 
    ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="User" List="UserInfo" Presence="FALSE" 
    Name="Author" DisplayName="Created By" ForcedDisplay="***" Sortable="FALSE" 
    Filterable="FALSE" AllowMultiVote="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" 
    StaticName="Author" FromBaseType="TRUE" />
```

The `Filterable="FALSE"` causes your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to change Author as filterable?

Answer (score 1):

I am fully agreed with Damjan Tomic. Author(Created By) field in survey lists is not filterable.

So you can't use REST with filtering by author.
But you can use CSOM or [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/) library

For example, code below checks is current user answered to survey or not

```
$().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "YOUR SURVEY LISTNAME",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                        "<Eq>" +
                            "<FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' />" +
                            "<Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value>" +
                        "</Eq>" +
                    "</Where>" +
                "</Query>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                alert($(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").length);
            }
        })
```